# Uncountable basis in Hilbert space vs orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

It is known that an infinite dimensional Banach space does not have a countable Hamel basis. It is also known that a separable Hilbert space has an orthonormal countable basis. Now, I think this basis is Schauder basis. So this means that a Banach space can have uncountable Hamel basis but a countable Schauder basis, right? Or am I missing something here?

By the way, do separable Banach(non-Hilbert) spaces also have countable Schauder bases? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: First question: yes. The "by the way": If a Banach space has a Schauder basis, then it is countable. (Not all separable Banach spaces have  a Schauder basis.)

Comment: @DavidMitra yes, I just saw that P. Enflo had given an example of a separable Banach space wiout a Schauder basis